# How to hide text if it is not homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example if i make a widget on wordpress, how can  show it only in homepage? Can i make a Javascript code that can show Div element only in homepage and if it isnot homepage to hide it? How can be such a code?

Comment: you should specify how your theme is made...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `is_home()` method in your template or you can define the sidebar only for the page where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the base url of homepage and see if it is the url display it else not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress, there are settings you can use to lock widgets down to certain pages. It really depends on the plugin you are using though.

If you have short codes, you can simply put the short code for that widget on just the pages you want to see it and not the ones you don't.

If not, there is usually a setting under the widget that should allow you to set the page it is displayed on or the pages you want to exclude it from. This would be in the Widgets tab in the wp-admin panel on the left side.

I would give you more specifics and even examples, but im not sure what plugins you are using. Give me a little more example of what you are working with and I will help you however I can. Good luck.